# Filter geoFire queries by certain criteria before populating viewHolder in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire, event-listener

I have successfully implemented geoFire to get the keys of entries from a main firebase node within the user's area.

I have then attempted to store those keys in a new, unique node, in order to use them later to populate a viewHolder, as this seems to be best practice.

The problem is that I don't want all of the objects stored in the unique node to actually populate the viewHolder; I only want a subset of them.

If I filter inside the populateViewHolder method, e.g.,

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    SwarmReport retrievedModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(SwarmReport.class);
    if(!retrievedModel.isClaimed()){
        viewHolder.bindSwarmReport(retrievedModel);
    }
}
```

I get some items in the viewHolder that are blank.

If, instead, I try to filter before setting up the FirebaseAdapter, e.g. in my addGeoQueryEventListener methods, I have to add an `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to check the criteria by which I aim to filter:

```
public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
    claimCheckKey = key;
    final DatabaseReference claimCheckRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("all").child(key);
    claimCheckRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            SwarmReport claimCheckSwarmReport = dataSnapshot.getValue(SwarmReport.class);
            if (!claimCheckSwarmReport.isClaimed()){
                swarmReportIds.add(claimCheckKey);
            }
        }
```

It seems that `onGeoQueryReady` executes before `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` in `onKeyEntered` is finished. Any recommendations on how to get `onGeoQueryReady` to wait for all of the swarmReportIds.add(claimCheckKey)s to complete?

In case it's helpful, here's a snapshot of my firebase structure:
[image]

Comment: Is there anything I can do to clarify the issue?

Comment: Have you found the answer to your problem?

Answer (score 5):

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve but I will take a guess and say that you want not only the closest `key` but you also want to filter the closest `key` based on some other criteria, e.g., closest restaurant then prices,

The workaround I did to achieve this, (still looking for better options) is to set a flag inside the `onDatachange` method that I called on inside the `onKeyentered` method, that compares entries inside that node, (for sake of argument we will say prices)

**UPDATE**

```
  @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(final String key, GeoLocation location) {
     final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("<your ref>"+key);
     db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                        String dishPrice=ds.getValue(String.class);
                        int price=Integer.parseInt(dishPrice);



                            if (price<=12) {

                                isMatch=true;

                            }


                    }
                    if(isMatch){
                        getRestaurants(key);
                    }
                    isMatch=false;


                }
```

And outside the for each loop of `onDataChange` I set to execute the function that populates the `arraylist` of my `adapter` only when the function is true

getRestaurants method

```
    private void getRestaurants(final String id) {

   final DatabaseReference temp=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getRef("<your 
 ref>"+id)
          temp.child(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
          ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                    Restaurant restaurant = dataSnapshot.getValue(Restaurant.class);  
                    restaurant.setName(restaurant.getName());
                    restaurant.setImageUri(restaurant.getImageUri());
                    restaurant.setUid(id);


                    //add elemens to arraylist


                        resList.add(restaurant);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
```

Another suggestion would be to make a function on the cloud, (assuming again) in your case that all you need is to monitor whether the value of "claimed" changes, so you can set an `onUpdate`event trigger or and `onWrite` and check the value in `onChanged()` and get the current value (true/false)after that you can make use of geoFire queries and get the close by users and update their nodes depending on the value.

[Event Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)

[Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

Comment: Thanks so much, @omar A.R! That gives me a good lead! Could I see your getRestaurants() method as well?

Comment: And actually seeing some more code surrounding the onDatachange method would be helpful, too!

Comment: please forgive me for being unable to work on this project for several weeks. I am able to focus on it again now. I'm confused how resList interacts with the adapter... does the adapter have access to resList? Is adapter of type FirebaseRecyclerAdapter??

Comment: adapter can be of type FirebaseRecyclerAdapter or any Recyclerviewadapter clas